# rounded values for color in d3 scale

Tags: colors, d3.js, range, scale

what i would like to do is to create not a range of colors for an output value, but a hard color based on the input. ie say i have:

```
color = d3.scale.linear().domain( [0,1,10] ).range( [ 'green', 'orange', 'red' ] )
d3.range(0,10).forEach( (d) ->
    console.log d + ' ' + color(d)
)
```

this would create a range of colors between orange and red. however, i would like:

```
0   = green
1-9 = orange
10  = red
```

in addition i would to be able to handle the `NaN` case such that it's gray.

i was playing with `ordinal` but i don't particularly want to specify all of the numbers for the `domain` (as my input may be a float).

how do i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [threshold scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#threshold-scales):

```
color = d3.scale.threshold()
          .domain([1, 10])
          .range(['green', 'orange', 'red'])

> color(0)
"green"
> color(1)
"orange"
> color(8)
"orange"
> color(10)
"red"
```

Comment: fantastic! how about the gray...? or will i have to process that separately?

Comment: Forgot about that! function safeColor(num){ return isNaN(num) ? 'grey' : color(num); }

Comment: yeah, i was wondering if there was some `scale` object that could do that, but i guess its better than hard coding it in my vis object. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of very specific behavior I would directly implement the `color` function by hand.

```
var color = function(d){
    if(isNaN(d)) return 'gray' //handle NaN 
    else if(d<0||d>10) return color(d%11) //handle out of range values
    else if(d==0) return 'green'
    else if(d==10) return 'red'
    else return 'orange'  
}
```

Comment: Well, Adam Pearce's answer is what you want ;-) 
I leave mine in case it might help a user with a related problem.

Comment: I was about to submit: "color = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1, 1, 9, 9, 10]).range( [ 'green', 'green', 'orange', 'orange', 'red', 'red' ] )". It seemed pretty ugly though so I double checked the api and there was a better solution just sitting there!

Comment: @ChristopherChiche I have the neat version of your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

In naked-javascript:

```
function colorScale(i) {
    return i >= 100 ? '#000' :
           i >= 75  ? '#333' :
           i >= 50  ? '#666' :
           i >= 25  ? '#999' :
                      '#fff' ;
}

console.log(colorScale(94));
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yLX8s/)